# Program is not returning to main function

Tags: c, function, return

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int taskchoice, a;

void Menu() {
    printf("What would you like to do: \n Fish = 1\n Hunt = 2 \n Cook = 3\n Boss = 4\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    if (a == 1) {
        Fishing();
    }
        
    if (a == 2) {
        printf("Hunting\n");
    }
        
    if (a == 3) {
        printf("Cooking\n");
    }

    if (a == 4) {
        printf("Bossing\n");
    }
    else {
       abort();
    }
}

void Fishing() {
    printf("Time to fish me lord?\n");
    return;
}
    
int main() {
    Menu();
    
    printf("Would you like to go back to the menu?");

    //my fishing function is working as intended but the question is, why does it not display
    //anything that is posted after the menu(); in the main function
    //I am new to C and thank you for taking the time to look at my question. 
}
```

Comment: If you enter any value except `4` then `abort()` will be called. Is the program missing some `else`s?

Comment: Yeah, if you dont pick a correct answer it is supposed to end. I have been pressing 1 to start the fishing function. the fishing function works but the program does not go back to main, therefore I cannot continue on programming.

Comment: Off-topic: There's no need to return from a `void` function as very last action, all you achieve by is inferior readability...

Comment: So I press 1 and it's says time to Time to fish me lord?, but why does it not go to Would you like to go back to the menu?

Comment: As I wrote, if you enter `1` then `Fishing()` will be called, and then because you did not enter `4`, the program will `abort()` instead of returning to `main`.

Comment: You call `printf("Would you like to go back to the menu?");` and then you're at the end of main and the program terminates...

Comment: Off-topic again, but important: `a` should not be a global variable, but a local one to `menu` function!

Comment: How would I make it go back to the main function then? I think I understand what you are saying, would it be because when it goes through again its showing up as NULL or something?

Comment: Talk to your rubber duck at each line of the `Menu()` function telling it what will happen next. You need to change some of the `if`s to `else if`.

Comment: Weather Vane, what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: I mean, explain to a listener, what each line will do. That should slow your thoughts down to see the flaw. Perhps the helpful edit will make it clearer.

Comment: The `else` pertains only to the last `if`, not all of them.

Comment: So the issue I was having was the multiple if statements and not the else-if statements?

Comment: Thank you Fred Larson!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, there are multiple occurrences of `if` statement, and the last `if-else` statement is what makes decides the returning path.

So instead of having multiple `if`, go with `if else-if`, because it is sure that the user will input a single `int` value.

Use the following in place of `Menu()` function:

```
void Menu() {
    printf("What would you like to do: \n Fish = 1\n Hunt = 2 \n Cook = 3\n Boss = 4\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    if (a == 1) {
        Fishing();
    }
        
    else if (a == 2) {
        printf("Hunting\n");
    }
        
    else if (a == 3) {
        printf("Cooking\n");
    }

    else if (a == 4) {
        printf("Bossing\n");
    }
    else {
       abort();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return value on main since you have a datatype for your main function.

```
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

If not change int main to void main.

Lastly remove void on your finish function. Since the function does not return anything. It returns back to main and ends the main function.